# Angular give card class active when clicked and remove active class when other card is clicked

Tags: jquery, angular, class, click, selected

I'm having trouble figuring out how to give a card a class of active when it is clicked and also remove it when another card is clicked. I found some posts on how to add an active class but not how to remove it when another card is clicked. How could I achieve this? The code that I am working with looks like this :

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="add-experience-form">

                    <mat-card *ngFor="let skillExp of skillExpArr">

                        <img src={{skillExp.imgPath}}>
                        <mat-card-title>{{skillExp.level}}</mat-card-title>
                        <mat-card-content>" {{skillExp.title}} "</mat-card-content>

                        <div *ngIf="!skillExp.slider ;else slider">
                            <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
                                <mat-radio-button value="1">I followed a workshop / <br>
                                    played around with it</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button value="5">Played with it for a week ,<br>
                                    I know the basics</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button value="10">Two weeks of experience </mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button value="20">I have my first solid <br>
                                    month of experience</mat-radio-button>
                            </mat-radio-group>
                        </div>

                        <ng-template #slider>
                            <p>{{skillExp.min}}</p>
                            <mat-slider [max]="skillExp.max" [min]="skillExp.min" [step]="skillExp.step" [thumbLabel]="true" [(ngModel)]="skillExp.value"></mat-slider>
                            <p>{{skillExp.max}}</p>
                            <div *ngIf="skillExp.value != 0"><p><span>{{skillExp.value}}</span> {{skillExp.sliderDescription}} experience</p></div>
                          </ng-template>

                    </mat-card>

      </div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
export class SkillExperienceComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}
  private sub: any;
  consultantId: number;
  skillname: string;
  skillExpArr: Array<any> = [
    {
      id: 1,
      level: 'Rookie',
      title: " I'm soooo new to this ",
      value: 0,
      imgPath: '../../../../../assets/JPG/rookie-exp.jpg',
      enabled: false,
      slider: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      level: 'Junior',
      title: ' I have the basics down ',
      value: 0,
      imgPath: '../../../../../assets/JPG/junior-exp.jpg',
      enabled: false,
      slider: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 12,
      step: 1,
      sliderDescription: 'months',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      level: 'Medior',
      title: " I'm a solid performer ",
      value: 0,
      imgPath: '../../../../../assets/JPG/medior-exp.jpg',
      enabled: false,
      slider: true,
      min: 1.5,
      max: 3.5,
      step: 0.5,
      sliderDescription: 'years',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      level: 'Senior',
      title: " I'm mastering this.. ",
      value: 0,
      imgPath: '../../../../../assets/JPG/senior-exp.jpg',
      enabled: false,
      slider: true,
      min: 4,
      max: 10,
      step: 1,
      sliderDescription: 'years',
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.consultantId = Number(params['id']);
      this.skillname = params['skillname'];
    });
  }

  navigateAddSkill() {
    this.router.navigate([`skillplatform/${this.consultantId}/add`]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `index` to do something like this

html:

```
<mat-card
  *ngFor="let skillExp of skillExpArr; let i = index;"
  [class.active]="selectedIndex === i"
  (click)="selectedIndex = i">
  ...
</mat-card>
```

ts:

```
export class SkillExperienceComponent implements OnInit {
selectedIndex = 0;
```

I used the index as the pointer but you can use a field on the `skillExp` object as well.

Comment: I was really overthinking it all! I thought it was going to be something difficult but it all makes sense now! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I ended up using the id of every object instead of the index because I already had it in place. Thanks again can't believe I didn't think of this myself.

Comment: @imkeVr Using `id` is a better pattern of course, good thinking! Another nice thing to keep in mind is that you can also leverage `trackBy` with the `id` to improve the performance inside an `ngFor` if necessary

Comment: I haven't used trackBy before so I will look into it thanks for the advice!